# Remote Control via TeamViewer on a Google Compute VM Instance

Tags: google-compute-engine, remote-desktop, teamviewer

I am running a Windows Server VM Instace on Google Compute Services...  I can access the instace via the "Windows Remote Desktop" no problem...  I could install Team Viewer on the instance...

Because of Firewall issues I cannot run "Windows Remote Desktop" from my desktop to access that VM (google compute) Instance...  Reason of why I installed Team Viewer on that VM instance...

The funny thing is that I can access that VM instance through Team Viewer Only, as long as it is connected through "Windows Remote Desktop" to a separate 3rd computer... (4G internet outside the firewall --of desktop trying to access the VM Instace through Team Viewer--).

Even if I minimize the "Windows Remote Desktop"on my laptop it will cut the connection through TeamViewer between the VM cloud instance and my Desktop computer...

Any help or ideas in there?  It seems that either Team Viewer isn't able to start or somehow either the VM Windows Server screen only runs when the "Windows Remote Desktop" is running....

As I get this message:

"The screen cannot be captured at the moment.  This is probably due to fast user switching or a disconnected/minimized Remote Desktop Session."

I did a complete version installation of TeamViewer as administrator, running on a Windows Server on google compute VM.

Hopefully someone out there can help me! I don't know if it may be part of the Google Compute Services Instance settings so as to limit the remote desktop only to the native "Windows Remote Desktop" program...  Or perhaps a setting were since it's a VM the screen is de-activated when the "Windows Remote Desktop" program is off or minimized etc...??

My main problem is having TeamViewer work without having to initiate the native Windows RDP...  In order for TeamViewer do it's job and take its place... as in the place where I am located (my desktop computer) the firewall blocks Windows RDP but does not block TeamViewer's.

I tried changing the listening port to different numbers....

According to the instructions here:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306759  and here:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304304/

Unfortunately.. when I changed it and then rebooted the Win Server 2008 VM, and checked to see if it made the change... I noticed  it goes back to be on the same port again.... (of course to connect I had to do it through the original port)...

So it changes it but on rebooting it goes back to be on the same port again... I don't know if it's either because the new port was being used or there is a policy somewhere directing it always to the original port again...

I enabled those ports also to work for RDP in the Google Compute Instance interface, but still it made no difference...

It doesn't seem TeamViewer has a setting to change the port it connects with etc...

Hopefully I can find someone knowing about this issue.... The AWS instance used to work fine with LogMe In at the time.... I may end up using AWS (Amazon Web Services) again as Google Compute Srvs. won't do the job... but it's much cheaper than the AWS isntance...  Thanks for helping...

Comment: I was able to reproduce the same issue. Maybe installing a terminal server  on your Google's windows instance will resolve this issue.

Comment: Thanks. How would I do that?

Comment: Funny thing.. I never experienced the same issue with AWS (Amazon Web Services) windows instance.

Comment: RE: Installing a terminal server.  I suppose you mean installing a windows server VM within that instance?

Comment: Installing a terminal Server on MS Server requires licensing sorry I forgot to mention that in my previous message. I tried also to sign in to team viewer with a created account and I was able to connect but there is some issues with the screen rendering. I will keep you posted if I figure out another "free" Solution.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? (thanks!!)

Comment: Hello, No I never managed to solved this, Thanks for asking...  I asked TeamViewer about it and they mentioned to me this options, one of them was to install the Team Viewer program directly on the server without RDP (something which I cannot do as it is not physically next to me). and the other was through the 'Services' option selecting 'This account' (under properties) and entering the account credentials...  I did that but it did not work either... I also tried re-installing the program just in case but to no avail...

Comment: George, thanks that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Ok here is the solution. You can install something different than TeamViewer which will work like a charm. I have installed radmin server and tried it and it works perfectly and you can also change the default port to any port. You can also install Logmein which also works perfectly.

Comment: Thank you!  I wonder if it will work through firewalls as Team Viewer does... (the good thing about Team Viewer is that it works through the firewall where I am currently located at on my desktop computer)... Also is there a free version of LogmeIn as there used to be in the past?  I think it should definitely work with LogMeIn... as I used to used that long ago on an Amazon Compute Instance...  But I thought I read somewhere it isn't available for free anymore...  Anyway thanks much for the suggestions, I'll try them out and let you know!

Comment: I had success with Radmin from my laptop using my cell connection... But I had no success from my desktop as the firewall blocks it!.....  I wish there was a way that it would allow Team Viewer to operate... as Team Viewer is set to work through firewalls and it works fine... the main problem is that an extra RDP connexion needs to be active and with an open window...

Comment: I also tried LogMeIn... to see if it would go through the firewall as TeamViewer does to no avail!....  In short... Team Viewer is good for it to go through the firewall but can't connect without an active RDP program window open... LogMeIn and Radmin works but cannot is not made to go through firewalls...

Comment: @Luis Why not changing the default port for Radmin and let it listen on the Team Viewer port? I believe the default port is 5938 for team-viewer. check and let me know. Also another solution would the chrome RDP extension.

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work.  The Radmin Viewer on my desktop does not go through the firewall and Team Viewer does not communicate with Radmin ...  Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: @Luis I didn't mean team viewer to communicate with Radmin, I said if you can change the default port for Radmin server to the same port as teamviewer maybe it will pass the firewall. What about the Chrome RDP extension?

Comment: Hi George,  thanks, Yes I experimented with both... as i didn't completely understand it, until now... so I did just that thinking that perhaps it would pass the firewall but no luck, it didn't... I changed the port to 5938 as you said.  TeamViewer is build to go through fire walls a traversal type of connection... I don't know what that means or what they do to accomplish that.

Comment: Hi George,  thanks, Yes I experimented with both... as I didn't completely understand it, until now... so I did just that (had Radmin port changed to 5938) thinking that perhaps it would pass the firewall.. but no luck, it didn't....  TeamViewer is build to go through fire walls a traversal type of connection... I don't know what that means or what they do to accomplish that.  I have tried Chrome RDP before and its the same thing... it doesn't go through the firewall.. Also I noticed that when using Radmin...Windows Remote Desktop got disconnected...

Comment: so it seems you cannot use both at the same time... even after having changed the port on Radmn... and if I remember well I think that the same case is for Chrome RDP... As if somehow they use the same windows RDP component....

Comment: @Luis As you were able to figure out the answer to this question can you post that as an answer and accept it. This will benefit others searching for the same issue.

Comment: Hello, I was never able to solve this issue....  Still got same problem, If anybody solves it it would be of great help!

Comment: Can you open a issue report using GCE issue tracker (https://code.google.com/p/google-compute-engine/issues/list). Don't forget to include all the steps to reproduce the issue with detailed information. Once done, I'll triage the report and forward to engineering for further investigation if required.

Comment: Thanks!  Will do when I get an chance and let you know.

Comment: I just posted this issue on  GCE issue tracker here: https://code.google.com/p/google-compute-engine/issues/detail?id=286&thanks=286&ts=1452188068  Hopefully someone will be able to look into this.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it happened due to slower network speed on the other side, of which I intend to take session.